# Django: How to pass values into value_from_datadict

Tags: html, django, textbox, widget

I am wondering how the value_from_datadict method determines which form inputs to extract and pass as its 'data' variable.

I have a custom widget that passes selected items from a checkbox list to the value_from_datadict method. Each checkbox selected passes a unique id value to the value_from_datadict. I also have a textbox beside each checkbox list item to which I want to give the user the ability to give a customizable name for each item.

The problem I am having is that I am not able to extract the textbox values into value_from_datadict.

Is there a way to tell the widget to also extract the textbox values?

Thank you.

**CODE EDIT**

```
# from models.py
class MyObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    myData = models.TextField()

    # other fields...

    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class myDataField(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    order = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

---

```
# from forms.py
class MyObjectEditForm(ModelForm):

    # other form fields...

    myData = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=MyWidget)

    def clean_myData(self):
        myData = self.cleaned_data['myData']
        if not literal_eval(myData):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Must have at least one instance.")
        return myData
```

---

```
# from form_page.html
<p>
    {{ form.myData.errors }}
    <label for="id_myData">MyData Types:</label>
    {{ form.myData }}
</p>
```

---

```
# from widgets.py
class MyWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.key_attrs = {}
        self.val_attrs = {}
        if "key_attrs" in kwargs:
            self.key_attrs = kwargs.pop("key_attrs")
        if "val_attrs" in kwargs:
            self.val_attrs = kwargs.pop("val_attrs")
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if not value:
            value = '{}'
        value = literal_eval(value)

        mDFs = MyDataField.objects.all() # get all MyDataField objects

        ret += '<div id="myData"><br>'
        ret += '<label for="myData"> MyData Types: </label>'
        ret += '<table>'
        for i in range(len(mDFs)):
            ret += '<tr><td>'
            ret += '<label for="id_myData_{}">'.format(k, typ, i)
            ret += '</td><td>'
            ret += '<input id="id_myData_{}" name="myData" type="checkbox" value="{}" {}>'.format(i, mDFs[i].pk, 'checked' if mDFs[i].pk in value.keys() else '')
            ret += ' {}</label>'.format(myDFs[i].name)
            ret += '</td><td>'
            ret += '<input id="id_txtbox_myData_{} name="txtbox_myData" type="textbox" value="{}">'.format(i, mDFs[i].name)
            ret += '</td></tr>'
            ret += '</table><br>'
            ret += '</div>'

        return mark_safe(ret)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):            
        myData_keys = []

        for k in data.keys():
            if k.startswith("myData"):
                myData_keys.append(k)

        myData_dict = {}

        # Not sure what to do here...

        return str(myData_dict) //serialized dict of all myData types
```

I basically want to combine the myData checkbox primary key in a tuple with the textbox input given beside it (pk, "customizableName") and then store that in the myData_dict.

The form looks something like this (crude):

[ checkbox ] < MyData Type1 label > [-------------------------------------    textbox   -----------------------------------   ]
[ checkbox ] < MyData Type2 label > [-------------------------------------    textbox   -----------------------------------   ]
[ checkbox ] < MyData Type3 label > [-------------------------------------    textbox   -----------------------------------   ]
[ checkbox ] < MyData Type4 label > [-------------------------------------    textbox   -----------------------------------   ]

etc...

Comment: Realized that I was missing a pair of quotes around the textbox name.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this in [the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L216): it's not very complicated, it's passed the data dict and a name parameter and by default it just gets the value from the key corresponding to the name.

If you're after something a bit more complex, perhaps the relevant code from [MultiWidget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L831) might be useful: there it just calls value_from_datadict for each child widget.

If you're still having trouble, you should probably paste the code for your widget.

**Edit**

There are a large number of things wrong with your code, but basically this is utterly the wrong approach.

I have no idea what you mean by "storing the data in the dict" - that's not what value_from_datadict is for at all, it's for returning a value to display in the widget - and I also can't imagine why you want to "serialize" the result, but the problems run much deeper than that.

Your widget should not be doing any of the things it is doing. Most specifically, it should not be querying the database and outputting inputs for each row. And it should not be including both checkbox and text input for each row, either. Normally if you wanted to do that you would use a [MultiWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultiWidget) as I mentioned above, but that's not really appropriate here either because of the need for multiple rows.

What you actually need here is not a custom widget at all, or even a custom field, but simply a formset. Each form in the formset can relate to a single MyData instance, and you can have a textfield and a booleanfield for each.

Comment: Added code. I tried looking at the snippet but I still don't know how to obtain data from the textboxes.

Could it be that my custom widget is not able to see the textboxes' values because of its html id tag/label or because it is not instantiated in forms.py?

Comment: Definitely a great approach that will be implemented if I need to overhaul this.

Thank you.